# Dropbox error about monitoring file system

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing

Dropbox gives me pop-up errors about not being able to monitor the file system (that quickly disappear) when it starts up but it still seems to work ok, why is that?

Comment: On what operating system are you running the Dropbox client? Are you able to obtain the full text of the error message?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On Linux, the Dropbox client is subject to a default system limit on the number of directories it can monitor for changes. There is a warning regarding this, along the lines of:

> Unable to monitor filesystem
>
> Please run: echo 100000 | sudo tee
>   /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches and restart Dropbox to correct
>   the problem.

This comes up often in the Dropbox Forums, and they have a mention of it in their ["Why aren't certain files on one computer syncing to another?"](https://www.dropbox.com/help/145) document:

> Monitoring more than 10000 folders
>
> The Linux version of the Dropbox desktop application is limited from
>   monitoring more than 10000 folders by default. Anything over that is
>   not watched and, therefore, ignored when syncing. There's an easy fix
>   for this. Open a terminal and enter the following:

```
> echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p
```

> This command will tell your system to
>   watch up to 100000 folders. Once the command is entered and you enter
>   your password, Dropbox will immediately resume syncing.

Comment: This does not explain the message suddenly appearing, when not changing the number of folders or files it needs to monitor. I changed files but not the number of files or directories. Next day I see that message. Any explanation for that?

Answer (score 4):

After multiple tries I was still getting the "unable to monitor filesystem" error.  I finally figured out why:

100,857 Files, 15,009 Folders

I had to bump my max_user_watches to a higher number.